# OwnCloud 10.2 on Lubuntu 18.04 - Cannot mount USB local drives

Tags: lubuntu, owncloud-server

first of all I've already asked this question in the OwnCloud forum but I didn't get any answer, so I thought I'd try here as well.

I'm running OwnCloud 10.2 on a Lubuntu 18.04 LTS server (just an old laptop). I have 4 USB NTFS drives connected to that laptop that I wanted to use as storage for OwnCloud. Using Lubuntu SMB I can read/write onto those drives from another Windows computer on the network. When I try to add them to OC though, OC throws me an error and cannot find the path.

On the server itself one of the drives path is /media/user/PB. Using that path OC cannot find it. If I, instead, try to share the default Lubuntu Music folder, OC can do it with no issues (/home/user/Music).

https://pastebin.com/v9R3zt4X Here's the content of the OC log, probably there are some errors there that I don't know how to decypher.

Thank you.

EDIT: for the sake of clarity here are some more details.

**Server:**
Operating system:
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release: 18.04
Codename: bionic

**Kernel:**
Linux multimedia 4.18.0-22-generic #23~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 6 08:37:25 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

**Web server:**
Server version: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
Server built: 2019-04-03T13:22:37

**Database:**
ii mariadb-client-10.1 1:10.1.40-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64 MariaDB database client binaries
ii mariadb-client-core-10.1 1:10.1.40-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64 MariaDB database core client binaries
ii mariadb-common 1:10.1.40-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 all MariaDB common metapackage
ii mariadb-server 1:10.1.40-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 all MariaDB database server (metapackage depending on the latest version)
ii mariadb-server-10.1 1:10.1.40-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64 MariaDB database server binaries
ii mariadb-server-core-10.1 1:10.1.40-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64 MariaDB database core server files

**PHP version:**
PHP 7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 (cli) (built: Jun 4 2019 14:48:12) ( NTS )
Copyright © 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright © 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.1, Copyright © 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies

**ownCloud version:**
[ownCloud ] 10.2.0 (stable)

[config.php for OC](https://pastebin.com/Vi42ts2A) (sensitive data already removed)

So all I did was installing Lubutnu 18.04 first, then OC 10.2 following the guide on their website. I also have SMB running on Lubuntu, so to access the drives as LAN shares from my home network.

So far, only the SMB share is working.

Comment: Did you give OC permission to read/write to that specific location?

Comment: That might be what I'm missing. could you please point me in the right direction? I'd have no idea how to.

Comment: You could automount the USBs and pass owner ship to OC. Let me draft up an answer.

Comment: Which error does Owncloud give you?

Comment: @vidarlo no errors per se, on the folder page in the web admin area there is a square to the left of the folder you're setting up. It goes green if it was found and mounted, otherwise goes red. Mine is red. There is OC log in the OP if you can make anything out of it. I couldn't.

Comment: I still think it is a ownership issue, have you made a persistent mount location for the USBs, and made www-data the owner of this location? You can check the permissions and owners with `ls -l`. You can add r/w by the `chmod 766`, where 7 is all permissions for the owner user, 6 for group and 6 for others.

Comment: @Dr_Bunsen the drive seem to be mounted, see
`root@multimedia:/etc/systemd# mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdb1 /media/vale/SAMSUNG/
Mount is denied because the NTFS volume is already exclusively opened.
The volume may be already mounted, or another software may use it which
could be identified for example by the help of the 'fuser' command.`

I also changed ownership with
`chown -R www-data /media/vale/SAMSUNG/`
and restarted Apache but nothing changed.

Also did `chmod 766 -R /media/vale/SAMSUNG/`, still nothing.

Comment: You shoudln't have to restart apache, but I think there is an issue, the device is already mounted, as /dev/sdb1? What is the output of `lsblk`? And can you as your user or root access either sdb1 or /media/vale/SAMSUNG ?

Comment: @Dr_Bunsen lsblk returns
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 232.9G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
└─sda2   8:2    0 232.4G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0   1.8T  0 disk
└─sdb1   8:17   0   1.8T  0 part /media/vale/SAMSUNG
sdc      8:32   0 931.5G  0 disk
└─sdc1   8:33   0 931.5G  0 part /media/vale/Volume
sdd      8:48   0 596.2G  0 disk
└─sdd1   8:49   0 596.2G  0 part /media/vale/PB
sde      8:64   0   1.8T  0 disk
└─sde1   8:65   0   1.8T  0 part /media/vale/Elements
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom

Comment: @Dr_Bunsen And yes I can access /media/vale/SAMSUNG both as root and as user. That's what I don't get, the drive seems mounted and working.

Comment: `ls -l` of the USB mount locations gives www-data as owner?

Comment: @Dr_Bunsen nope, it's vale (my username). So here's what I've done:
`root@multimedia:/media/vale# chown -R www-data /media/vale/Volume/`
changing ownership
`root@multimedia:/media/vale# ls -l`
checking that ownership got transferred
`totale 52
drwxrwxrwx 1 vale vale  4096 Jun 20 15:46 Elements
drwxrwxrwx 1 vale vale  4096 Oct  7  2018 PB
drwxrwxrwx 1 vale vale 40960 Jun 19 18:11 SAMSUNG
drwxrwxrwx 1 vale vale  4096 Jan 27 17:56 Volume`
Ownership did not change. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hmm, I would expect that too work. I am not sure why it doesn't. Have you tried asking in an IRC channel? Maybe they can diagnose it faster than out little comments here ;)

Answer (score 0):

OwnCloud(php / www-data) probably doesn't have the right to read/write to the location of the USBs.
You could change the ownership of the location where they are mounted(assuming you dabbled in fstab to keep them mounted after a reboot)  with

`$ chown -R owner-user:owner-group directory`

Where for owner-user and owner-group should be `www-data`. I am not sure if php is a member of this group by default, if it is not, use `$ adduser php www-data` to make php a member of www-data.

Note that giving write access to php is somewhat debatable, but this should make OwnCloud recognise and be able to use the USB sticks.

More about chown and chmod [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-use-chmod-and-chown-command/)

Comment: First of all thank you. It appears I dont have a php user from cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd but I do have a www-data user.
I then ran the chown -R www-data:www-data /media/vale/SAMSUNG/ command, no errors in SSH, restarted apache but no change, still cannot add that drive to OC. What am I missing?

Comment: I couldn't tell you without all the relevant data. So in your question add: OS + version, what have you installed(php, apache etc), what OC requires and what steps you took to make this work.

Comment: I've modified the original post with some comments, let me know if it's not enough.